# How to set variable encoding when debug php/java in vscode?

Tags: java, php, debugging, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I'm using macOS, vscode and xdebug for PHP. I saved the file in GBK encoding and have set "files.encoding": "gbk" in settings.json. So the files dispalyed in workspace are all correct. But when I debug and break, the variables displayed like "���ǡ��ȼӹ��ﳵ�".

I've  searched the internet but failed to find where to set encodings for the variables when debugging?

Any ideas would be appreciate!

Cheers!